# Error in Decision tree in shiny ctree

Tags: r, tree, server, shiny, regression

I'm trying of building a tree using 'partykit' library in R within a shiny app.

This tree works fine in the console with same dataset and variables. Actually if I force to work only with a fixed group of two variables it gives me back same error. This is the reactive function which launchs the ctree function and the function which gives me the error back

'Error : is.factor(y) || isTRUE(all.equal(round(y), y)) || is.data.frame(y) is not TRUE'

```
runTree <- reactive({
if(is.null(input$fichero))
{return()}
if (input$split==0){dat<-data()}
else {dat<-train()[[1]]}
# dat<-data()
if (is.null(input$columns) || !(input$columns %in% names(dat)))
  return()
if (is.null(input$columnsvartreeindep))
  return()
dat<-dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]
dat$Visits<-as.numeric(dat$Visits)
dat$Volume<-as.numeric(dat$Volume)
arbol_ctree_total<-ctree(control=ctree_control(teststat = c("quad", "max"),
                                               testtype = c("Bonferroni","Univariate", "Teststatistic"),
                                               mincriterion = 0.95, minsplit = 20L, minbucket = 50L,
                                               minprob = 0.01, stump = FALSE, maxsurrogate = 0L, mtry = Inf,
                                            maxdepth = Inf, multiway = FALSE, splittry = 2L, majority = FALSE),Volume~Visits, data=dat)
return(arbol_ctree_total)  
})
```

Anyone could know what is the problem??

NEW EDIT

DATASET

dput(file_tree)
structure(list(Wgebiet. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), .Label = c("AARGAU", "BAS-VALAIS", 
"BASEL", "BERNER MITTELLAND", "BERNER OBERLAND", "BERNER SEELAND", 
"BUENDNER OBERLAND", "BUENDNER UNTERLAND", "FRIBOURG", "GENEVE", 
"GLARUS", "JURA", "LIECHTENSTEIN", "LUZERN, OW, NW", "NEUCHATEL", 
"OBERWALLIS", "SCHAFFHAUSEN", "SOLOTHURN", "ST. GALLEN, AI, AR", 
"THURGAU", "TICINO", "URI/SCHWYZ", "VAUD", "ZUG", "ZÜRICH"), class = "factor"), 
    YearMonth = c(NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 
    20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 
    201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 
    20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 
    201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 
    20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 
    20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 
    20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 
    20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 
    201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 
    20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 
    20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 
    20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 
    20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 
    201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 
    20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 
    20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, 
    NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 
    20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 
    201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 
    20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 
    20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 
    20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 
    20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 
    201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 
    20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 
    20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, 
    NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 
    20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 
    201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 
    20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 
    20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 
    20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 
    20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 
    201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 
    20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 
    20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, 
    NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 
    20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 
    201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 
    20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 
    20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 
    20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 
    20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 
    201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 
    20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 
    20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, 
    NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 
    20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L,

```
20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 
20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 
20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 
20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 
201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 
20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 
20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, 
NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 
20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 
201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 
20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 
20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 
20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 
20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 
201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 
20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 
20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L, 
NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 
20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 20151L, 201510L, 
201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 20155L, 20156L, 
20157L, 20158L, 20159L, NA, 20141L, 201410L, 201411L, 201412L, 
20142L, 20143L, 20144L, 20145L, 20146L, 20147L, 20148L, 20149L, 
20151L, 201510L, 201511L, 201512L, 20152L, 20153L, 20154L, 
20155L, 20156L, 20157L, 20158L, 20159L), Volume = c(1, 307, 
362, 320, 374, 304, 334, 359, 356, 365, 386, 332, 351, 300, 
336, 325, 361, 291, 346, 339, 349, 368, 389, 327, 348, 1, 
412, 455, 407, 446, 399, 430, 452, 447, 456, 463, 417, 442, 
384, 400, 397, 437, 372, 419, 415, 424, 441, 453, 396, 414, 
1, 196, 241, 192, 238, 193, 214, 223, 226, 239, 247, 206, 
233, 200, 220, 204, 227, 197, 224, 219, 222, 236, 254, 215, 
228, 1, 364, 413, 363, 423, 342, 391, 408, 411, 410, 439, 
385, 398, 341, 390, 378, 427, 335, 395, 383, 406, 425, 443, 
388, 402, 1, 100, 165, 75, 168, 85, 111, 131, 138, 139, 198, 
135, 136, 87, 106, 97, 172, 71, 128, 110, 130, 171, 201, 
158, 120, 1, 113, 183, 112, 186, 96, 159, 176, 187, 191, 
195, 157, 178, 95, 160, 132, 182, 92, 174, 163, 180, 199, 
213, 138, 170, 1, 566, 559, 515, 26, 551, 567, 560, 528, 
25, 24, 2, 17, 524, 552, 516, 30, 530, 10, 508, 519, 16, 
23, 562, 9, 1, 94, 119, 69, 134, 68, 93, 111, 107, 111, 164, 
77, 109, 61, 86, 73, 118, 59, 90, 76, 88, 108, 161, 74, 98, 
1, 209, 242, 212, 253, 202, 229, 239, 245, 243, 265, 210, 
246, 192, 252, 250, 255, 203, 240, 249, 234, 268, 270, 232, 
267, 1, 449, 506, 457, 505, 444, 494, 495, 502, 539, 507, 
445, 500, 438, 461, 448, 468, 428, 493, 459, 467, 503, 499, 
454, 466, 1, 29, 55, 27, 49, 28, 34, 52, 41, 51, 62, 31, 
42, 22, 35, 33, 54, 21, 39, 32, 36, 46, 64, 33, 43, 1, 56, 
74, 58, 91, 44, 63, 72, 89, 88, 99, 48, 78, 38, 45, 40, 60, 
31, 61, 50, 53, 65, 70, 37, 47, 1, 146, 259, 147, 257, 148, 
156, 155, 256, 262, 261, 151, 260, 144, 145, 150, 149, 143, 
154, 149, 153, 257, 258, 152, 147, 1, 317, 394, 315, 369, 
313, 341, 373, 375, 354, 405, 329, 353, 311, 333, 337, 381, 
306, 355, 343, 357, 382, 403, 331, 380, 1, 133, 181, 137, 
190, 115, 173, 187, 177, 189, 193, 116, 188, 114, 162, 129, 
179, 99, 169, 166, 167, 185, 194, 117, 175, 1, 511, 545, 
486, 559, 508, 527, 533, 514, 531, 9, 532, 537, 489, 517, 
479, 555, 490, 526, 514, 512, 540, 7, 518, 544, 1, 520, 558, 
513, 565, 510, 543, 547, 536, 562, 4, 538, 554, 478, 521, 
524, 546, 473, 535, 528, 525, 561, 568, 529, 534, 1, 281, 
328, 285, 321, 280, 298, 316, 312, 322, 345, 292, 310, 276, 
295, 287, 318, 274, 302, 299, 308, 319, 347, 293, 305, 1, 
366, 393, 360, 387, 325, 376, 371, 404, 420, 422, 350, 386, 
323, 358, 379, 370, 326, 377, 367, 338, 409, 401, 344, 392, 
1, 230, 269, 216, 279, 205, 217, 264, 244, 272, 266, 238, 
237, 184, 207, 225, 221, 211, 263, 248, 231, 235, 251, 208, 
218, 1, 284, 319, 277, 301, 275, 297, 314, 303, 330, 352, 
288, 324, 273, 283, 278, 289, 271, 290, 294, 286, 309, 340, 
282, 296, 1, 436, 521, 435, 485, 433, 472, 491, 483, 488, 
541, 475, 481, 432, 475, 474, 487, 434, 477, 480, 482, 509, 
550, 476, 484, 1, 429, 471, 440, 497, 421, 460, 464, 469, 
498, 501, 426, 470, 416, 458, 450, 492, 418, 465, 451, 462, 
496, 504, 431, 461, 1, 549, 15, 548, 11, 542, 563, 12, 8, 
18, 20, 553, 13, 523, 556, 554, 5, 522, 564, 566, 6, 14, 
19, 557, 3, 1, 81, 126, 80, 125, 67, 105, 124, 121, 140, 
142, 79, 123, 66, 84, 82, 122, 57, 104, 101, 102, 127, 141, 
83, 103), Visits = c(1, 221, 67, 32, 242, 228, 7, 27, 5, 
21, 18, 223, 66, 64, 146, 108, 92, 73, 71, 41, 208, 68, 77, 
96, 74, 1, 12, 129, 49, 54, 236, 47, 45, 50, 62, 22, 11, 
35, 116, 160, 145, 131, 120, 138, 47, 11, 124, 143, 83, 119, 
1, 41, 21, 246, 204, 15, 27, 48, 45, 176, 9, 198, 172, 39, 
25, 103, 38, 37, 28, 14, 232, 223, 25, 39, 205, 1, 39, 102, 
69, 76, 22, 76, 65, 68, 56, 35, 52, 120, 125, 144, 147, 104, 
115, 104, 53, 7, 134, 88, 62, 130, 1, 164, 204, 203, 203, 
161, 206, 213, 205, 198, 188, 196, 212, 240, 8, 9, 239, 233, 
4, 204, 184, 216, 154, 199, 249, 1, 154, 216, 210, 176, 164, 
203, 198, 206, 176, 177, 178, 233, 206, 239, 8, 247, 192, 
192, 165, 156, 15, 8, 203, 8, 1, 169, 70, 156, 175, 2, 215, 
126, 13, 2, 142, 241, 163, 188, 1, 241, 202, 110, 122, 78, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 202, 1, 122, 186, 226, 193, 78, 152, 176, 163, 
51, 204, 186, 226, 220, 220, 205, 186, 230, 221, 198, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 188, 1, 196, 246, 239, 178, 203, 224, 238, 19, 221, 
16, 200, 242, 18, 23, 220, 221, 6, 6, 224, 192, 236, 35, 
218, 40, 1, 80, 104, 102, 54, 85, 114, 125, 132, 120, 91, 
21, 97, 111, 162, 159, 157, 105, 123, 96, 38, 155, 148, 121, 
191, 1, 187, 158, 172, 165, 13, 142, 142, 165, 101, 174, 
168, 186, 204, 203, 200, 158, 199, 198, 165, 2, 156, 161, 
142, 165, 1, 198, 195, 200, 175, 196, 228, 184, 221, 172, 
195, 173, 227, 213, 232, 225, 193, 227, 211, 173, 101, 203, 
122, 199, 10, 1, 187, 51, 13, 169, 169, 229, 93, 241, 150, 
24, 202, 3, 13, 202, 93, 241, 24, 13, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 13, 
1, 67, 67, 75, 47, 46, 83, 107, 84, 10, 31, 226, 64, 100, 
141, 137, 74, 130, 103, 83, 18, 87, 104, 99, 118, 1, 230, 
247, 231, 224, 4, 247, 28, 14, 235, 224, 232, 9, 250, 49, 
55, 249, 22, 18, 235, 200, 19, 198, 17, 62, 1, 13, 93, 2, 
1, 150, 78, 101, 86, 169, 110, 93, 93, 1, 170, 156, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 154, 164, 161, 168, 151, 70, 142, 
154, 154, 164, 158, 122, 205, 213, 230, 170, 175, 158, 163, 
156, 165, 211, 199, 177, 1, 245, 57, 50, 15, 242, 26, 29, 
27, 14, 10, 12, 49, 54, 113, 112, 83, 30, 48, 250, 224, 82, 
90, 54, 99, 1, 228, 63, 61, 10, 204, 29, 36, 54, 248, 10, 
38, 49, 84, 95, 103, 40, 89, 72, 33, 20, 64, 17, 90, 90, 
1, 204, 240, 12, 231, 188, 240, 210, 249, 236, 220, 234, 
245, 14, 49, 32, 11, 57, 26, 240, 199, 246, 239, 43, 18, 
1, 249, 63, 59, 28, 67, 89, 117, 72, 23, 14, 45, 64, 23, 
44, 67, 244, 59, 22, 48, 66, 47, 112, 81, 53, 1, 70, 133, 
122, 42, 51, 133, 110, 86, 34, 51, 241, 78, 165, 192, 170, 
154, 158, 156, 34, 202, 133, 142, 122, 152, 1, 58, 106, 88, 
38, 98, 109, 111, 135, 79, 118, 44, 77, 128, 166, 128, 119, 
127, 140, 100, 63, 139, 123, 149, 138, 1, 241, 51, 94, 229, 
60, 110, 101, 110, 202, 24, 34, 34, 126, 168, 165, 110, 156, 
151, 94, 24, 86, 126, 110, 136, 1, 159, 189, 182, 180, 153, 
181, 190, 194, 167, 183, 171, 185, 201, 243, 237, 219, 207, 
197, 179, 129, 217, 222, 209, 214), Payments = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 63L, 39L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 78L, 1L, 112L, 
1L, 147L, 36L, 115L, 110L, 105L, 27L, 91L, 86L, 75L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 32L, 149L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
97L, 1L, 61L, 1L, 96L, 1L, 106L, 121L, 7L, 144L, 1L, 37L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 71L, 1L, 
73L, 80L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 121L, 143L, 1L, 1L, 122L, 24L, 
58L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 67L, 89L, 124L, 50L, 16L, 
121L, 15L, 150L, 1L, 145L, 1L, 21L, 139L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 132L, 
84L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 100L, 152L, 27L, 
31L, 1L, 118L, 90L, 46L, 1L, 22L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 141L, 99L, 75L, 1L, 
38L, 138L, 127L, 46L, 92L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 83L, 1L, 51L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 46L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 34L, 32L, 153L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 
85L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 52L, 32L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 1L, 106L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 137L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 
1L, 1L, 8L, 125L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
94L, 1L, 33L, 93L, 42L, 44L, 60L, 17L, 1L, 30L, 148L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 75L, 1L, 69L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 67L, 130L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 153L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 78L, 87L, 1L, 1L, 59L, 107L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 134L, 140L, 133L, 28L, 13L, 65L, 62L, 4L, 48L, 40L, 
23L, 83L, 88L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 131L, 1L, 27L, 46L, 60L, 2L, 
1L, 121L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 67L, 1L, 105L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 50L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 91L, 1L, 135L, 
116L, 109L, 101L, 79L, 46L, 26L, 45L, 1L, 1L, 113L, 14L, 
68L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 126L, 114L, 119L, 128L, 
6L, 35L, 136L, 1L, 104L, 1L, 77L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 83L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 134L, 121L, 148L, 1L, 121L, 142L, 
43L, 53L, 1L, 49L, 70L, 29L, 134L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 103L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 95L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 40L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 81L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
40L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 151L, 66L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 47L, 89L, 82L, 57L, 83L, 83L, 106L, 60L, 121L, 
146L, 129L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 148L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 72L, 55L, 120L, 1L, 111L, 74L, 154L, 9L, 108L, 155L, 
41L, 76L, 20L, 98L, 56L, 123L, 54L, 102L, 117L, 16L, 64L, 
12L, 16L), .Label = c("", "1000.00", "102.00", "10235.00", 
"10240.00", "10373.00", "10400.00", "10420.00", "10669.00", 
"1100.00", "11000.00", "11171.00", "11410.35", "11440.35", 
"11489.00", "11500.00", "11600.00", "1200.00", "12470.00", 
"12943.00", "12974.00", "13000.00", "137.00", "13700.00", 
"1390.00", "1462.00", "1500.00", "1512.00", "1558.35", "15700.00", 
"15900.00", "1600.00", "16350.00", "167.00", "1680.00", "17000.00", 
"1710.00", "1750.00", "1778.00", "1800.00", "18500.00", "19197.00", 
"1965.00", "19700.00", "1990.00", "2000.00", "2100.00", "21472.00", 
"216.00", "2200.00", "23.00", "2300.00", "2310.00", "2341.00", 
"23711.00", "23721.00", "23934.00", "24662.65", "250.00", 
"2500.00", "25170.00", "258.00", "2606.00", "26757.00", "28816.00", 
"2960.00", "3000.00", "3150.00", "3200.00", "3216.65", "3370.00", 
"33970.00", "3400.00", "3443.00", "3500.00", "3531.00", "3621.00", 
"3800.00", "3802.00", "3820.00", "39.00", "3920.00", "400.00", 
"4000.00", "4100.00", "4180.00", "4200.00", "4250.00", "4300.00", 
"4360.00", "4400.00", "4433.40", "45100.00", "4520.00", "4560.00", 
"4600.00", "4720.00", "4753.00", "480.00", "4800.00", "4840.00", 
"48850.00", "4890.00", "4900.65", "498.00", "500.00", "5052.00", 
"5110.00", "5200.00", "5258.00", "5300.00", "5350.00", "5383.00", 
"5450.00", "5500.00", "5550.00", "5660.00", "578.00", "5799.00", 
"5924.00", "600.00", "6000.00", "60629.00", "6066.65", "6300.00", 
"64.90", "645.00", "6450.00", "6520.00", "6700.00", "6780.00", 
"685.00", "6900.00", "700.00", "7171.00", "728.50", "7400.00", 
"750.00", "7514.60", "752.00", "7600.00", "7660.00", "7670.00", 
"768.00", "7700.00", "7733.00", "776.00", "800.00", "8044.00", 
"8290.00", "8320.00", "8500.00", "900.00", "9100.00", "9425.00"
), class = "factor"), PromoProd = structure(c(1L, 76L, 237L, 
229L, 244L, 92L, 124L, 108L, 203L, 196L, 188L, 200L, 217L, 
218L, 144L, 181L, 213L, 129L, 191L, 120L, 197L, 244L, 225L, 
188L, 170L, 1L, 97L, 219L, 214L, 234L, 98L, 106L, 102L, 213L, 
176L, 217L, 218L, 215L, 240L, 217L, 205L, 228L, 176L, 216L, 
147L, 194L, 238L, 232L, 219L, 203L, 1L, 145L, 150L, 230L, 
256L, 135L, 167L, 138L, 102L, 112L, 135L, 134L, 161L, 233L, 
194L, 206L, 247L, 150L, 180L, 132L, 203L, 216L, 227L, 197L, 
185L, 1L, 67L, 229L, 233L, 255L, 94L, 119L, 122L, 208L, 183L, 
198L, 219L, 218L, 241L, 183L, 199L, 227L, 139L, 170L, 126L, 
203L, 239L, 232L, 212L, 155L, 1L, 50L, 210L, 187L, 211L, 
61L, 66L, 68L, 184L, 180L, 182L, 154L, 207L, 137L, 142L, 
168L, 192L, 80L, 118L, 83L, 142L, 174L, 167L, 154L, 126L, 
1L, 53L, 189L, 214L, 209L, 92L, 113L, 111L, 233L, 186L, 188L, 
173L, 203L, 151L, 155L, 179L, 176L, 84L, 104L, 64L, 146L, 
185L, 152L, 125L, 137L, 1L, 21L, 115L, 92L, 170L, 38L, 47L, 
37L, 60L, 91L, 95L, 89L, 122L, 155L, 148L, 137L, 182L, 98L, 
129L, 70L, 110L, 151L, 166L, 137L, 124L, 1L, 32L, 225L, 201L, 
209L, 55L, 78L, 74L, 162L, 145L, 117L, 157L, 197L, 155L, 
166L, 163L, 208L, 105L, 146L, 110L, 171L, 198L, 196L, 205L, 
181L, 1L, 145L, 185L, 231L, 254L, 153L, 153L, 125L, 182L, 
149L, 141L, 149L, 199L, 246L, 167L, 198L, 193L, 142L, 161L, 
99L, 184L, 202L, 198L, 151L, 154L, 1L, 133L, 201L, 246L, 
259L, 156L, 159L, 161L, 183L, 129L, 123L, 153L, 205L, 249L, 
171L, 194L, 213L, 131L, 160L, 106L, 196L, 201L, 178L, 154L, 
161L, 1L, 29L, 201L, 170L, 199L, 52L, 78L, 81L, 185L, 177L, 
140L, 141L, 183L, 157L, 145L, 130L, 164L, 122L, 154L, 102L, 
173L, 171L, 162L, 131L, 127L, 1L, 60L, 175L, 193L, 186L, 
122L, 85L, 38L, 30L, 38L, 54L, 72L, 175L, 66L, 88L, 135L, 
113L, 36L, 111L, 53L, 133L, 143L, 146L, 113L, 107L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 17L, 14L, 6L, 57L, 
31L, 28L, 9L, 39L, 24L, 42L, 24L, 21L, 28L, 44L, 1L, 50L, 
222L, 216L, 235L, 82L, 109L, 95L, 211L, 201L, 190L, 182L, 
217L, 199L, 151L, 195L, 224L, 112L, 169L, 103L, 171L, 190L, 
185L, 183L, 166L, 1L, 135L, 182L, 248L, 243L, 159L, 179L, 
138L, 132L, 102L, 107L, 144L, 179L, 159L, 138L, 152L, 158L, 
101L, 132L, 89L, 196L, 205L, 185L, 160L, 136L, 1L, 16L, 69L, 
87L, 126L, 39L, 24L, 41L, 79L, 66L, 76L, 85L, 125L, 45L, 
91L, 78L, 106L, 43L, 69L, 50L, 122L, 125L, 107L, 77L, 59L, 
1L, 12L, 80L, 101L, 62L, 27L, 35L, 40L, 104L, 80L, 86L, 95L, 
114L, 22L, 99L, 114L, 84L, 26L, 64L, 46L, 119L, 126L, 90L, 
75L, 68L, 1L, 51L, 221L, 201L, 204L, 83L, 102L, 93L, 206L, 
188L, 178L, 182L, 217L, 163L, 146L, 177L, 204L, 90L, 134L, 
98L, 173L, 206L, 204L, 175L, 142L, 1L, 39L, 226L, 211L, 245L, 
83L, 107L, 91L, 203L, 199L, 184L, 202L, 217L, 212L, 175L, 
220L, 224L, 141L, 190L, 107L, 165L, 211L, 204L, 197L, 184L, 
1L, 23L, 144L, 161L, 176L, 47L, 58L, 63L, 177L, 144L, 98L, 
131L, 188L, 96L, 123L, 172L, 164L, 71L, 97L, 73L, 152L, 173L, 
148L, 115L, 116L, 1L, 94L, 238L, 215L, 232L, 116L, 121L, 
117L, 187L, 193L, 225L, 207L, 201L, 184L, 234L, 241L, 252L, 
138L, 194L, 159L, 236L, 244L, 231L, 225L, 237L, 1L, 18L, 
112L, 101L, 87L, 48L, 49L, 56L, 99L, 65L, 97L, 120L, 144L, 
50L, 128L, 110L, 134L, 34L, 107L, 84L, 130L, 138L, 100L, 
97L, 106L, 1L, 156L, 213L, 250L, 262L, 172L, 204L, 195L, 
230L, 183L, 186L, 177L, 210L, 261L, 223L, 249L, 260L, 214L, 
229L, 173L, 223L, 233L, 238L, 215L, 205L, 1L, 13L, 99L, 112L, 
80L, 19L, 20L, 33L, 112L, 67L, 60L, 76L, 156L, 55L, 111L, 
81L, 118L, 25L, 75L, 50L, 114L, 111L, 99L, 74L, 95L, 1L, 
89L, 249L, 238L, 258L, 108L, 141L, 145L, 217L, 234L, 247L, 
242L, 221L, 257L, 237L, 243L, 253L, 218L, 245L, 179L, 244L, 
255L, 251L, 228L, 233L), .Label = c("", "158.00", "188.00", 
"189.00", "191.00", "200.00", "204.00", "215.00", "216.00", 
"229.00", "235.00", "248.00", "249.00", "250.00", "251.00", 
"256.00", "281.00", "285.00", "296.00", "303.00", "306.00", 
"307.00", "309.00", "310.00", "314.00", "315.00", "317.00", 
"318.00", "320.00", "322.00", "327.00", "336.00", "339.00", 
"341.00", "343.00", "344.00", "345.00", "347.00", "348.00", 
"350.00", "352.00", "355.00", "357.00", "358.00", "361.00", 
"362.00", "363.00", "364.00", "366.00", "369.00", "372.00", 
"374.00", "375.00", "376.00", "380.00", "381.00", "384.00", 
"385.00", "386.00", "387.00", "389.00", "390.00", "392.00", 
"393.00", "396.00", "398.00", "399.00", "400.00", "403.00", 
"404.00", "405.00", "406.00", "408.00", "409.00", "410.00", 
"411.00", "412.00", "413.00", "415.00", "418.00", "419.00", 
"421.00", "422.00", "423.00", "424.00", "426.00", "427.00", 
"430.00", "431.00", "432.00", "434.00", "435.00", "436.00", 
"437.00", "438.00", "439.00", "440.00", "441.00", "442.00", 
"443.00", "446.00", "447.00", "448.00", "449.00", "450.00", 
"451.00", "452.00", "454.00", "455.00", "456.00", "457.00", 
"458.00", "460.00", "461.00", "462.00", "463.00", "464.00", 
"465.00", "466.00", "467.00", "469.00", "471.00", "472.00", 
"473.00", "474.00", "476.00", "477.00", "478.00", "479.00", 
"480.00", "481.00", "482.00", "483.00", "484.00", "487.00", 
"488.00", "489.00", "490.00", "491.00", "492.00", "493.00", 
"494.00", "495.00", "496.00", "497.00", "498.00", "499.00", 
"500.00", "501.00", "502.00", "503.00", "504.00", "505.00", 
"506.00", "507.00", "508.00", "509.00", "510.00", "511.00", 
"512.00", "513.00", "514.00", "515.00", "516.00", "517.00", 
"518.00", "519.00", "520.00", "521.00", "522.00", "523.00", 
"524.00", "525.00", "526.00", "527.00", "528.00", "529.00", 
"530.00", "531.00", "532.00", "533.00", "534.00", "535.00", 
"536.00", "537.00", "538.00", "539.00", "540.00", "541.00", 
"542.00", "543.00", "544.00", "545.00", "546.00", "547.00", 
"548.00", "549.00", "550.00", "551.00", "552.00", "553.00", 
"554.00", "555.00", "556.00", "557.00", "558.00", "559.00", 
"560.00", "561.00", "562.00", "563.00", "564.00", "565.00", 
"566.00", "567.00", "568.00", "569.00", "570.00", "571.00", 
"572.00", "573.00", "574.00", "575.00", "577.00", "578.00", 
"580.00", "581.00", "582.00", "584.00", "585.00", "586.00", 
"587.00", "588.00", "589.00", "590.00", "591.00", "592.00", 
"593.00", "596.00", "597.00", "598.00", "599.00", "600.00", 
"601.00", "603.00", "604.00", "608.00", "609.00", "612.00", 
"616.00", "620.00", "621.00", "624.00", "627.00", "629.00", 
"632.00", "634.00", "635.00", "644.00", "648.00", "661.00", 
"669.00"), class = "factor"), Facings = structure(c(1L, 15L, 
14L, 17L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 13L, 
12L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 1L, 
9L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 
11L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 19L, 11L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 20L, 
10L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 
10L, 1L, 19L, 13L, 21L, 23L, 19L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 
16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 1L, 28L, 15L, 13L, 21L, 25L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 
12L, 20L, 15L, 18L, 16L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 19L, 13L, 
22L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 21L, 16L, 19L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
17L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 17L, 16L, 
16L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 12L, 7L, 10L, 
5L, 7L, 12L, 8L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 11L, 16L, 11L, 16L, 14L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 
13L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 
12L, 11L, 1L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 20L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 16L, 
15L, 20L, 14L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 19L, 16L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 21L, 10L, 6L, 15L, 26L, 20L, 6L, 
12L, 17L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 20L, 12L, 19L, 14L, 15L, 
12L, 17L, 12L, 1L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 18L, 13L, 11L, 18L, 14L, 
14L, 15L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 17L, 
15L, 17L, 14L, 13L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 19L, 7L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 
15L, 29L, 32L, 18L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 15L, 16L, 
1L, 1L, 30L, 30L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 9L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 8L, 17L, 9L, 14L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 
18L, 14L, 17L, 14L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 16L, 10L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 
14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 14L, 12L, 19L, 24L, 19L, 16L, 14L, 
17L, 17L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 12L, 
14L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
6L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 8L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 17L, 13L, 10L, 16L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 8L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
10L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 
13L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 
24L, 17L, 16L, 1L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 
13L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 10L, 
8L, 10L, 10L, 19L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 
11L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 31L, 27L, 24L, 9L, 27L, 10L, 5L, 
8L, 18L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 10L, 2L, 20L, 
9L, 9L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 10L, 18L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 
16L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 24L, 8L, 22L, 4L, 
5L, 10L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 21L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 
14L, 7L, 19L, 1L, 16L, 12L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 
13L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 19L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 19L, 17L, 12L, 
15L, 12L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("", "0.15", "0.16", "0.17", 
"0.18", "0.19", "0.20", "0.21", "0.22", "0.23", "0.24", "0.25", 
"0.26", "0.27", "0.28", "0.29", "0.30", "0.31", "0.32", "0.33", 
"0.34", "0.35", "0.36", "0.37", "0.38", "0.39", "0.40", "0.44", 
"0.47", "0.48", "0.51", "0.74"), class = "factor"), Contracts = structure(c(1L, 

1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"1.00", "10.00", "11.00", "12.00", "12470.00", "14.00", "18.00", 
"19.00", "2.00", "23.00", "25.00", "28.00", "3.00", "38.00", 
"4.00", "42.00", "5.00", "6.00", "7.00", "9.00"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Wgebiet.",
```

"YearMonth", "Volume", "Visits", "Payments", "PromoProd", "Facings", 
"Contracts"), row.names = c(NA, -625L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you post an example of the data/input so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: The problem is in the data input because if I say before that     # Volume<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,9,9,9,5,4)
    # Visits<-c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,65,6)
    # dat<-data.frame(Volume,Visits) It just works fine!! But I don't understand because I've used same code with a regression and it works perfectly...

Comment: So this 'dat<-dat[, input$columns, drop = FALSE]' doesn't work and I don't really why. Like I said before. I've used this piece of code in many many outputs and always works fine in order to select those input variables I need to plot, tabulte or doing a regression.

Comment: This is the piece of code which works fine in the console ith same data so it's not a data issue I think. "file_tree<-read.csv2(file='E:/faces/Month Results CH ALL.txt',dec=";",head=TRUE)" and there we launch the tree       "arbol_ctree_total<-ctree(control=ctree_control(teststat = c("quad", "max"),
  testtype = c("Bonferroni","Univariate", "Teststatistic"),
  mincriterion = 0.95, minsplit = 20L, minbucket = 50L,
  minprob = 0.01, stump = FALSE, maxsurrogate = 0L, mtry = Inf,
   maxdepth = Inf, multiway = FALSE, splittry = 2L, majority = FALSE),Volume~Visits, data=file_tree)"

Comment: Its really hard to help find error without the data. Can you use dput to get the structure of you data and post that

Comment: I've tried to use dput but I cant fit all the data in the screen. I've had to cut a little bit the dataset. i hope it will be enough. Thanks in advance!!